# I want to add dynamic input and textarea elements to form in and angular app

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Currently I am having 3-4 input elements which have been hidden initially and I have binded them to variable new element is shown after clicking enter. I want to focus on the newly added item after user clicks enter. I have handled the enter button event in a function handleKeyDown.

create-report.html

```
<form class="form" (submit)="submit($event)">
  <div class="loginmodal-container">
    <br>

    <div class="row form-group">
     <input (keyup.enter)="handleKeyDown($event)" [(ngModel)]="title"  id="title" aria-describedby="titlehelp" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Enter Post Title" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="row form-group">
       <input id="industry" (keyup.enter)="handleKeyDown($event)" [class.display]="titleflag" aria-describedby="indushelp" type="text" name="industry" placeholder="Enter Industry" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="row form-group">
           <input id="desc" (keyup.enter)="handleKeyDown($event)" [class.display]="indusflag" aria-describedby="deschelp" type="text" name="desc" placeholder="Enter your report description" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <!-- <div id="adddata" align='left'>
        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
    </div> -->

    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="login loginmodal-submit" value="Post Report">

  </div>
  </form>
```

create-report.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-create-report',
templateUrl: './create-report.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./create-report.component.css']
})
export class CreateReportComponent implements OnInit {

title = '';
industry = '';
desc = '';
titleflag = false;
indusflag = false;
constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
}
submit(e) {
e.preventDefault();
}
private handleKeyDown(event: any) {
  const target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.currentTarget;
  const idAttr = target.attributes.id;
  const getid = idAttr.nodeValue;
if (event.keyCode === 13) {
  if ( getid === 'title' ) {
    if ( target.value !== '' ) {
      this.titleflag = true;
    }
  }
  if ( getid === 'industry' ) {
    if ( target.value !== '' ) {
      this.indusflag = true;
      event.srcElement.nextElementSibling.focus();
      }
    }
  }
 }

}
```

I also want to add new elements like we create new story in medium blog. Is there any way to add that to this angular app?

[image]